# Extracting intrinsicMatrix for external application from IPhone

Tags: ios, swift, camera, computer-vision

How can I extract the built in intrinsic matrix of an IPhone? I need this value for a Computer Vision application outside of Swift. Apple provides the [following function call](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcameracalibrationdata/2881135-intrinsicmatrix) to access the parameter, but I have no experience with SWIFT and exporting these values. What is the fastest way to obtain the return value of:

```
var intrinsicMatrix: matrix_float3x3 { get }
```

Thanks!